# Accessing contents of a class through parameter in java?

Tags: java

i need to access the contents of a `class` in this case: `ParkingMeter` through the parameters of another method in another class: `public static void checkTheCar(ParkedCar pc, ParkingMeter pm)` but not sure how to do that. the method `checkTheCar` has to retrieve a integer from `ParkingMeter` and check if its in the right range.
any advice is appreciated.

```
public static class ParkingMeter {

    int time;

    public ParkingMeter(int hours,int minutes){
         time = (getMinutes(hours,minutes));

    }
     private int getMinutes(int hours, int minutes){
            int time = (hours * 60) + minutes;
         return time;
        }
}

public static class ParkedCar{

    String CompanyName;             // Company name
    String Model;                   // Car model
    String Color;                   // Car color
    String PlateNumber;             // License plate number
    String Minutes;                 // number of minutes parked 

    public ParkedCar(String companyName, String model, String color,String plate, String minutes){
        CompanyName = companyName;
        Model = model;
        Color = color;
        PlateNumber = plate;
        Minutes = minutes;
    }
 }
public static class PoliceOfficer{
   String OfficerName;
   String BadgeNumber;

   public PoliceOfficer(String name,String badge){
       OfficerName = name;
       BadgeNumber = badge;
   }
   public static void checkTheCar(ParkedCar pc, ParkingMeter pm){
       // do something

   }

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class design needs some work.  4 things for starters... 1) Encapsulation of instance data - private instance vars with getters/setters 2) use camelCase on your variable names  3) please note the changes to the way you were setting up/accessing your data in the parking meter class. 4) added a toString() method in your ParkedCar class to make it easy to print out a result in your main program.

```
public class Parking {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //PoliceOfficer po = new PoliceOfficer("John Policeman", "4599BDG");
        ParkedCar pc = new ParkedCar("Lexus", "IS250", "White", "7GHK111", 90);
        ParkingMeter pm = new ParkingMeter(2, 30);
        PoliceOfficer.checkTheCar(pc, pm);
    }

    public static class ParkingMeter {

        private int time, hours, minutes;

        public ParkingMeter(int hours, int minutes) {
            this.hours = hours;
            this.minutes = minutes;
            setTime(hours, minutes);
        }

        private void setTime(int hours, int minutes) {
            this.time = (hours * 60) + minutes;
        }
        public int getTime() {
            return time;
        }

        public int getHours() {
            return hours;
        }
        public void setHours(int hours) {
            this.hours = hours;
        }

        public int getMinutes() {
            return minutes;
        }
        public void setMinutes(int minutes) {
            this.minutes = minutes;
        }

    }

    public static class ParkedCar {

        private String make; // Company name
        private String model; // Car model
        private String color; // Car color
        private String plateNum; // License plate number
        private int minutes; // number of minutes parked

        public ParkedCar(String make, String model, String color,
            String plate, int minutes) {
            this.make = make;
            this.model = model;
            this.color = color;
            this.plateNum = plate;
            this.minutes = minutes;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return color + " " + make + " " + model + ", plateNum=" + plateNum + " ";
        }

    }

    public static class PoliceOfficer {
        private String officerName;
        private String badgeNumber;

        public PoliceOfficer(String name, String badge) {
            this.officerName = name;
            this.badgeNumber = badge;
        }

        public String getOfficerName() {
            return officerName;
        }

        public void setOfficerName(String officerName) {
            this.officerName = officerName;
        }

        public String getBadgeNumber() {
            return badgeNumber;
        }

        public void setBadgeNumber(String badgeNumber) {
            this.badgeNumber = badgeNumber;
        }

        public static void checkTheCar(ParkedCar pc, ParkingMeter pm) {
            System.out.println(pc.toString() + " has been parked for : " + pm.getTime() + " minutes");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: great answer but i was wondering why you used `@Override` thanks.

Comment: @Ronald : Because toString() is an inherited method from Object and it is being overridden here.  This annotation specifies this.  While it is not necessary to use it to make the code compile (though some other annotations do require that), it is a best practice to use the this annotation whenever overriding any methods from inherited classes or interfaces.

Comment: @Ronald : Should probably add getters/setters to ParkedCar as well to make the design consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a public method `getTime` at the `ParkingMeter` class

```
public static class ParkingMeter {

int time;

public int getTime() {
  return time;
}

public ParkingMeter(int hours,int minutes){
     time = (getMinutes(hours,minutes));

}
 private int getMinutes(int hours, int minutes){
    int time = (hours * 60) + minutes;
    return time;
 }}
```

And in the **checkTheCar** you use it like that:

```
public static void checkTheCar(ParkedCar pc, ParkingMeter pm){
   int time = pm.getTime();
 }
```